# python "in" function doesn't work as expected for arrays

Tags: python, numpy

Example:

```
import numpy as np

blah = np.array([['10.12.5.40', 0],
                 ['10.12.5.40', 1],
                 ['10.12.5.40', 2]])

print(['10.12.5.40', 2] in blah)

print(['10.12.5.40', 10] in blah)
```

The first usage of `in` works correctly, giving `True` for an existing element in the `array`. However, the second usage asks for a non-existing element but `True` is returned nevertheless.

Comment: Do you mean _NumPy_ arrays?

Comment: Used it without array and got correct results

Comment: What is `array` here? `numpy.array`? `array.array`?

Comment: I meant numpy.array

Comment: Because `in` when working with `numpy.ndarray`s is asking `(x == arr).any()`. Fundamentally, you are confused about what consists of an "element" in a `numpy` array (it isn't a "row"), and how elementwise `==` works.

Comment: Also note, you are creating an array of unicode objects - the `int`s in your second columns get implicitely cast. Honestly, it doesn't look like you should be using `numpy` arrays at all...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: numpy arrays are fine, but they should be using a structured dtype here